# How to set up Azure Data Factory alerts & metrics via azure devops release pipelines?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I need to set up some alerts for my adf instance. I can do it only via release pieplines as there is sufficient servicie principle assigned.

Normally I would just click through alert tab but in this case I have to approach this problem differently.

Is it possible to modify alerts via release pipelines?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as of now you can't.

Azure Data Factory utilizes Azure Resource Manager (ARM) templates to store the configuration of your various ADF entities. Entities on `Alert` and `Metrics` don't get exported in the ARM template and therefore can't be integrated in the Azure DevOps.

For practical verification, you can export Data Factory's ARM template and observe that there aren't Alert and Metrics parameters.

Refer: [How To Export/Import An Azure Data Factory ARM Template](https://datamajor.net/how-to-export-import-an-azure-data-factory-arm-template/)

Comment: Okay, what about some api/programitcal way of doing it? Can it be done via some powershell scripts then ? (still azure devops)

Comment: I'm not sure so can't say anything. refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-programmatically once. might be helpful.